# MySQL using `IN` while having multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count of coupons sold by each store from the list of stores within 20 miles range. I know the following syntax will work if there is only 1 store.

SELECT sum(couponscount) as count where `restaurant` IN (SELECT `storename` where bhal bhal bhal and output is one value)

What is I the `IN (SELECT`storename`where bhal bhal bhal and output is multiple values)` will return multiple values?

Like in my case the complete SQL is like and its not working

```
SELECT sum(couponscount) as count FROM `coupons` having `restaurant` IN (SELECT `storename`, ((ACOS(SIN(-27.561264299999998 * PI()/180) * SIN(latitude * PI()/180) + COS(-27.561264299999998 * PI()/180) * COS(latitude * PI()/180) * COS((153.07304890000003 – longitude) * PI()/180)) *180 / PI( )) *60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `stores` WHERE `status`=’active’ HAVING `distance` <=20)
```

Is there anyway to make it working?

Comment: How is it not working?  What is the problem?

Comment: You need to move the distance condition from the SELECT to WHERE.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: When you see HAVING without GROUP BY there is usually something wrong with the query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Not in mysql...

Comment: @Mihai: Yes, also in MySQL. It usually shows that the author of the query doesn't exactly know what he/she is doing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(couponscount) AS COUNT,restaurant
FROM `coupons`
WHERE `restaurant` IN
    (SELECT `storename`
     FROM `stores`
     WHERE `status`='active'           
       AND
      ((ACOS(SIN(-27.561264299999998 * PI()/180) * SIN(latitude * PI()/180) + COS(-27.561264299999998 * PI()/180) * COS(latitude * PI()/180) * COS((153.07304890000003 – longitude) * PI()/180)) *180 / PI()) *60 * 1.1515) <=20)
GROUP BY restaurant
```

Also use proper quotes for active.

Comment: Still didn't work even after your edited the answer. Error `Unknown column 'latitude' in 'having clause'` but that `latitude` is used column in the table but there is something wrong in your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to get the count of coupons from stores within a distance of 20.  Moving the `having` condition to a `where` clause should do what you want:

```
SELECT sum(couponscount) as count
FROM `coupons`
WHERE `restaurant` IN (SELECT `storename`
                       FROM `stores`
                       WHERE `status` = 'active' AND
                              ((ACOS(SIN(-27.561264299999998 * PI()/180) * SIN(latitude * PI()/180) + COS(-27.561264299999998 * PI()/180) * COS(latitude * PI()/180) * COS((153.07304890000003 – longitude) * PI()/180)) *180 / PI( )) *60 * 1.1515) <= 20
                      );
```

You had a major syntax problem because your subquery returned two columns.  When you use a subquery with `in`, you can only return one column, in this case, `storename`.  I moved the code for the distance calculation to the `where` clause.  No `having` clause is needed either in the subquery or the outer query.

Comment: Lol, that returned complete count of all `stores` but I need `count` per each store so that I can use a while loop in php